# I want to created Keyword driven framework, how can we do that with csv file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, frameworks

Hi All I want too create keyword driven framework , I want to have java code to read keyword from csv file and map it to function in my framework . Many example given but based on excel not in csv

Can anyone help me out on this

Comment: Can you consider show us your work please? Thanks

Comment: @Dev : I havent written anything around it , i have framework where with testNG in selenium but that is not keyword driven, i want to have code to read csv file for keyword and will map those keyword function to reusable function

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/  if you want to work with csv files. When you can parse the csv, it's only a matter of setting up your framework with keyword functions. Still, I would advise to use excel or XMLs + JAXB for keyword driven testing with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful to take a look on the following GitHub repository.

https://github.com/qasquare/KeywordDrivern.TestNg

It proposes the same idea you mentioned. However the repository uses Apache POI to read XLSX files you can easily change the methods to read a CSV file.